# Pivot Table Lookup

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have a problem on replacing a text:
In a sheet I have an ID number and in another sheet I have a the ID + the name.
I want to use kind of lookup to substitute the ID in the first sheet with the corresponding name in the second sheet. Note that values are in columns.

```
ID
U298709
U297052
U297023
U504537
```

and

```
ID      Name
U298709 Mike
U297052 John
U297092 Frank
U502219 Lucy
```

Comment: welcome at superuser. Why do you stat pivot table in the title, is your data a pivot table? why do you specify **lookup** in the title and write **replace** in the question? please clarify your question to help us understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data begins with the labels in A1 of each sheet:

`=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A2:B4,2,false)`